# Selenium WebDriver.wait does not wait Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, safari, webdriver

I want to have Selenium wait until a webpage is loaded. I use Safari 14.1.2 on macOS 10.15.7

So I tried as below:

````
// login process and it successes and the following page shows up
login_submit.click() 

// the page after the authorization, make selenium wait until ```hoge``` is clickable
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'hoge')))
````

This code does not work as expected. It fails with an error `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchFrameException:`. The error comes immediately, which seems there is no 10 s wait.

The stack trace is as below: (Paths are modified.)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/login.py", line 99, in <module>
    login_schedule().quit()
  File "/login.py", line 67, in login_schedule
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'HOGEHOGE')))
  File "/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 71, in until
    value = method(self._driver)
  File "/selenium/webdriver/support/expected_conditions.py", line 64, in __call__
    return _find_element(driver, self.locator)
  File "/selenium/webdriver/support/expected_conditions.py", line 415, in _find_element
    raise e
  File "/selenium/webdriver/support/expected_conditions.py", line 411, in _find_element
    return driver.find_element(*by)
  File "/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchFrameException: Message:
```

When I put `time.sleep(10)` instead as below,

````
import time
// login process and it successes and the following page shows up
login_submit.click() 

time.sleep(10)
// the page after the authorization, make selenium wait until ```hoge``` is clickable
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'hoge')))
````

it works as expected.
Note that the last part can even be replaced

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='hoge']")
```

What is wrong with my Python code?

Comment: Are you sure there's no frame ? Also, can you try this `visibility_of_element_located` like this : `WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'hoge'))).click()`

Comment: Actually I am not sure... However as I wrote, it works(without no frame exception) after 10 sec wait..  and I tried ```visibility```, the result is almost same as the previous one.

Comment: Is it possible to share link of the web page ?

Comment: also it is in safari, that has few bugs in it, can you try the same with Chromedriver as well ?

Comment: Using Chrome, it works well...

Comment: hmm.. as mentioned Safari has bugs, you can switch to chrome or gecko

Comment: Probably, it is the best choice.. fortunately no constraint about browsers.. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use this function to wait until the element or something appears:

```py
def wait_for(xpath):
  while True:
    try:
      driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath) 
      return True
    except NoSuchElementException:
      continue
```

do not forget

```py
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
```

you can use anything it is not important to be XPATH as a method.

Comment: Thank you I will use it